# How to remove blue outline of select option in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/V69nK/1/) and am seeking how to get rid of that blue outline for drop-down select button and the Search inbox inside the drop down menu. See this image:

[image]

I already tried:

```
.btn-default {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
input, textarea, select, a { outline: none !important; }
input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{ outline: none; }
```

but they are not doing the trick.

Comment: I believe that is the :focus

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bootstrap form input elements do not use the `outline` property, but rather recreate it using `box-shadow`. You were on the right track with what you were doing, but the style that causes this is the following:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

You will want to override those styles with your own, setting the `box-shadow` to `none` and adjusting the `border-color` to match your default.

As for the select box, you can use the following style, as was originally mentioned by @kamlesh-kushwaha, to override the bootstrap setting:

```
.bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Blake this was very helpful for but how about the select button?

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part when answering.. it was mentioned in another answer, but I've added the selector for that part to my answer, for completeness

Answer (score 5):

For `<select>` dropdown, change in **bootstrap-select.min** line 29:

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: thin dotted #333 !important;
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color !important;
    outline-offset: -2px;}
```

to:

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus {
    outline: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I remove bootstrap 4 dropdown-toggle 'on click' blue borders by doing this:

```
.yourdivname:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Anything else seemed to be irrelevant. For instance, with normal buttons {outline: none} always seemed to work, but not for this element. All that was needed was the box-shadow:none property.

Answer (score 3):

Add the css `focus` rule or modify the existing one.

```
.bootstrap-select .btn:focus{outline:none!important;}
```

Similarly, you can add for `select`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input[type] {}`

All bootstrap input type as below

```
textarea:focus, 
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus, 
input[type="datetime"]:focus, 
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, 
input[type="date"]:focus, 
input[type="month"]:focus, 
input[type="time"]:focus, 
input[type="week"]:focus, 
input[type="number"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
input[type="url"]:focus, 
input[type="search"]:focus, 
input[type="tel"]:focus, 
input[type="color"]:focus, 
.uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
    /* give your style */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* give your style */
    outline: 0 none;
    /* give your style */
}

select:focus {
   outline-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap or not, you can remove the the outline from a `select` tag with with:

```
select:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```